# How to add additional buttons to the standard listactivity?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am loading names from a webservice which will always contain max 30 names. This names i can show with the listactivity, but if there are more than 30 names at the server i need a next and previous button at the bottom of the listactivity.

Is it possible to solve this with the listactivity or do i need to make my custom activity for this?

Thanks

Comment: you can add a `footer View` to your `LisView`.see [this].(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) for example see [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: why not using ScrolView?

Comment: @MahdiGiveie I just give you a thought!!! is it correct to use `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`??

Answer (score 2):

Try a layout file something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" >

            <!-- Put buttons here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

As long as your `ListView` has the resource id of `@android:id/list` the `ListActivity` will find it automatically. You'll need to assign resource ids to the `Buttons` and use `findViewById(...)` after using `setContentView(...)` to get references to the `Buttons`.